# Pages folder in a React-DOM project with ASP.NET

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

unfortunately I was unable to understand the purpose of the PAGES folder (created automatically) in a React-DOM project integrated with ASP.NET CORE.
I had this doubt because as far as I know, React is a library that allows the creation of single-page front-end applications (SPA), and that means that all rendering of the html elements will be performed on the client side. But this PAGES folder has Views (files with extension .cshtml) that are intended for the RAZOR engine, which performs the rendering of html elements on the server side.
So what are these Views for, since the rendering will only happen on the client side with React?
in advance, thank you for your attention ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "ASP.NET Core with React.js" template to create the project, which would help create a React project to act as a UI frontend and a ASP.NET Core Web API as an API backend.

In my opinion, for handling errors might occur in ASP.NET Core Web API, it helps [configure a custom error handling page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-page) by calling `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")`, and the template provides this Error page in the *Pages* folder.

Comment: Fei Han, thank you very much for the answer, in fact it makes a lot of sense.